# Using the entity framework with a MySQL DB and the model designer doesn't pickup stored proc parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I've got the latest Mysql connector that allows you to use the Visual Studio Entity Framework designer.  It's been working great, but I just added a stored proc.

The Server Explorer loaded it up fine with the parameters specified, but then I added it to the Entity Model & the code it generates doesn't have any input parameters.

Here's the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetViewableMenuNodes`(IN siteId INT, IN parentId INT, IN userName varchar(255))
BEGIN
    select m.*
    from menunode m 
    where m.siteid = siteId
    and m.showinmenu = 1
    and m.parentid = parentId
    and m.viewername = userName;
END
```

and this is the code generated by the model

```
public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<MenuNode> GetViewableMenuNodes()
{
    return base.ExecuteFunction<MenuNode>("GetViewableMenuNodes");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this bug entry:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44985

Sorry about your luck.  Welcome to the club.  Apparently having proper support for stored procedures in MySQL from the MySQL Connector/.NET Entity Framework is not available.  As you can see from the dates in the thread there has been an incredibly slow response to introduce the feature.

Answer (score 6):

In case you find this helpful, here is the approach I use for working with stored procedures with parameters in MySQL from the MySQL Connector/.NET Entity Framework provider.  I call ExecuteStoreQuery().  This liberates me from having to deal with the challenges of mapping procedures with parameters in the model.  This works for our needs.

```
    public IList<SearchResultsMember> SearchMembers(int memberID, string countryCode, string regionCode, string cityCode, float distanceKm,
        int genderID, int ageMin, int ageMax, int offsetRowIndex, int maxRows)
    {


        MySqlParameter[] queryParams = new MySqlParameter[] { 
                                        new MySqlParameter("memberIDParam", memberID),
                                        new MySqlParameter("countryCodeParam", countryCode),
                                        new MySqlParameter("regionCodeParam", regionCode),
                                        new MySqlParameter("cityCodeParam", cityCode),
                                        new MySqlParameter("distanceKmParam", distanceKm),
                                        new MySqlParameter("genderIDParam", genderID),
                                        new MySqlParameter("ageMinParam", ageMin),
                                        new MySqlParameter("ageMaxParam", ageMax),
                                        new MySqlParameter("offsetRowIndexParam", offsetRowIndex),
                                        new MySqlParameter("maxRowsParam", maxRows)
                                    };

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("CALL search_members(@memberIDParam, @countryCodeParam, @regionCodeParam, @cityCodeParam, @distanceKmParam, @genderIDParam, @ageMinParam, @ageMaxParam, @offsetRowIndexParam, @maxRowsParam)");

        string commandText = sb.ToString();
        var results = _context.ExecuteStoreQuery<SearchResultsMember>(commandText, queryParams);

        return results.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: `ExecuteStoreQuery` doesn't exist when I use EF with MySql, what version of EF do you have?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little extension we did for doing StoredProcedures on our DbContext:

```
    public static List<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(this DbContext dbContext, string storedProcedureName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        string storedProcedureCommand = "CALL " + storedProcedureName + "(";

        List<object> augmentedParameters = parameters.ToList();

        storedProcedureCommand = AddParametersToCommand(storedProcedureCommand, augmentedParameters);

        storedProcedureCommand += ");";

        return dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>(storedProcedureCommand).ToList<T>();
    }

    public static List<T> ExecuteStoredRecursiveProcedure<T>(this DbContext dbContext, string storedProcedureName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        string storedProcedureCommand = "SET max_sp_recursion_depth = " + maxRecursionCount + "; CALL " + storedProcedureName + "(";

        List<object> augmentedParameters = parameters.ToList();

        storedProcedureCommand = AddParametersToCommand(storedProcedureCommand, augmentedParameters);

        storedProcedureCommand += ");";

        return dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>(storedProcedureCommand).ToList<T>();
    }

    private static string AddParametersToCommand(string storedProcedureCommand, List<object> augmentedParameters)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < augmentedParameters.Count(); i++)
        {
            storedProcedureCommand = AddParameterToCommand(storedProcedureCommand, augmentedParameters, i);
        }
        return storedProcedureCommand;
    }

    private static string AddParameterToCommand(string storedProcedureCommand, List<object> augmentedParameters, int i)
    {
        if (augmentedParameters[i].GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            storedProcedureCommand += "'";
        }

        storedProcedureCommand += (augmentedParameters[i].ToString());

        if (augmentedParameters[i].GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            storedProcedureCommand += "'";
        }

        if (i < augmentedParameters.Count - 1)
        {
            storedProcedureCommand += ",";
        }

        return storedProcedureCommand;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I like this parameter approach more secure as it can handle the sql injection problems as well. I made it generalized as follows with :

```
public DbRawSqlQuery<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(string storedProcedureName, params object[] parameters)
        {            string storedProcedureCommand = "CALL " + storedProcedureName + "(";

            List<object> augmentedParameters = parameters.ToList();

            MySqlParameter[] queryParams;
            storedProcedureCommand = AddParametersToCommand(storedProcedureCommand, augmentedParameters, out queryParams);

            storedProcedureCommand += ");";



            return ((DbContext)this).Database.SqlQuery<T>(storedProcedureCommand, queryParams);
        }



        private string AddParametersToCommand(string storedProcedureCommand, List<object> augmentedParameters, out MySqlParameter[] queryParams)
        {
            string paramName = "";
            queryParams = new MySqlParameter[augmentedParameters.Count()];
            for (int i = 0; i < augmentedParameters.Count(); i++)
            {
                paramName = "p" + i;
                queryParams[i] = new MySqlParameter(paramName,augmentedParameters[i]);                                
                storedProcedureCommand += "@" + paramName;

                if (i < augmentedParameters.Count - 1)
                {
                    storedProcedureCommand += ",";
                }
            }
            return storedProcedureCommand;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Also note one most important thing when dealing with mysql database; always name the stored procedures parameters differently with the table column names otherwise its mixed up in the query inside the sp.

For example:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `authenticate_user`(
IN p_login_name varchar(50),
IN p_password varchar(80)
)
BEGIN

SELECT `user`.`user_id`,
    `user`.`login_name`,
    `user`.`password`
from users
where `login_name` = p_login_name
and `password` = p_password;

END
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample of my code got it working with VS2012 and Mysql connector 6.8.3 just generate your datamodel same as usual and dont forget to include the stored procedures.

Hope this help's someone.

```
public static IList<MyClass> GetCustOrderHist(string someParameter)
    {
        IList<MyClass> data = ((IObjectContextAdapter)TestDashboardEntities).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyClass>("CALL CustOrderHist({0});", someParameter).ToList();

        return data;
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int TOTAL { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It was my solution to call a stored procedure. I hope usefull.

```
MovieDbEntities db = new MovieDbEntities();
int id = 2;
var result = db.Movie.SqlQuery($"CALL SP_ReadMovie({id})").ToList();
```

Comment: That syntax isn't supported with MySQL there is only a `Query<Type>` method which is pretty limited

Comment: @djack109 did you find a resolution to this?