# Store Procedure not return value in MVC5

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working in MVC5 with Entity Framework through db approach. I use Mysql as database. I create a procedure and when **Call Procedure** in Mysql it work as my expectation. But when i use procedure in MVC it return every time 0.

**Store Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `checkSeasonAvailability`( 
    IN paramSeasonId INT,   
    IN paramHotelId INT,
    IN paramStartDate varchar(20),
    IN paramEndDate varchar(20)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _startDate,_endDate DATETIME;
    DECLARE _hotelseasonID BIGINT(20);
    DECLARE _count,_rowCount,_dateDiff INT;
    DECLARE _index INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cursorSeasonList CURSOR FOR SELECT `hotel_season_id`,`start_date`,`end_date`
            FROM    hotel_season_link
            WHERE   hotel_id    =   paramHotelId        &&
                    season_id   =   paramSeasonId       &&
                    active      =   TRUE;
    OPEN cursorSeasonList;
    SET _rowCount=FOUND_ROWS();
    SET _count=_rowCount;
    IF(_rowCount>0) THEN                    
        Proc:WHILE _index <= _rowCount DO
            FETCH cursorSeasonList INTO _hotelseasonID,_startDate,_endDate;
            SET _dateDiff=datediff(paramEndDate,paramStartDate);
            SET i=0;
            WHILE i <= _dateDiff DO

                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hotel_season_link
                WHERE
                        adddate(paramStartDate,i) BETWEEN _startDate AND _endDate INTO _count;

                IF(_count>0) THEN
                    SELECT 1;
                    LEAVE Proc;     
                END IF;
                SET i=i+1;
            END WHILE;
        SET _index=_index+1;
        END WHILE;
    END IF;    
END

CALL checkSeasonAvailability(1,3,'2014-12-26 00:00:00','2014-12-31 00:00:00');//call in mysql
```

**Controller**

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
var status = db.checkSeasonAvailability(seasonId, hotelId, startDate.ToString(format), endDate.ToString(format));
```

When i debug my code i find all required parameter send successfully but i didn't get return value.
If any thing wrong in my code so please suggest me.

Comment: Check these ressources out:

http://sunali.com/2012/10/10/querying-mysql-using-entity-framework-and-mysql-stored-procedures/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011062/using-the-entity-framework-with-a-mysql-db-and-the-model-designer-doesnt-pickup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve this problem by myself. I make changed in store procedure and action method.

I add one more parameter in my procedure as **OUTPUT** and store return value in this variable.

```
OUT Flag int

SET Flag=0;
SELECT Flag;
```

Then make change in action method.

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter flag = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("flag", typeof(int));
var status = db.checkSeasonAvailability(hotelSeasonId,seasonId, hotelId, startDate.ToString(format), endDate.ToString(format), flag);
```