# Stored procedure is not returning values in MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to execute a stored procedure and return the result to the view, after debugging my parameter is passed into the stored procedure, but it returns nothing and ends up in error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type  System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1[SocialAuthentication.Models.User   s, but this dictionary requires a model item of type     SocialAuthentication.Models.Users.

I have understood that I have declared the model as string the expected output is different how do I fix it.

My model

```
public class Users
{   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home"))
{
  <input id="Text1" type="text" name="txtOne" />
  <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="button" />
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact()
{
  string textboxValue = Request.Form["txtOne"];
  var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<Users>("usp_searchuser, @UserInput", new SqlParameter("@UserInput", textboxValue));
  return View(result);  
}
```

Stored procedure

```
CREATE procedure usp_searchuser --'Sara Nani'
    @UserInput varchar(50)
As
Begin
    select 
        Email, Name 
    from 
        tblEmployee 
    where 
        Name = @UserInput
End
```

Comment: Monitor the SP in SQL Profiler and see what craziness is occuring

Comment: Check out this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596869/store-procedure-not-return-value-in-mvc5

Answer (score 0):

there shouldn't be a comma after usp_searchuser in your call. That makes it an illegal SQL query.