# MVC Database-first - Calling a stored procedure and getting an error

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, dbcontext

I have a database-first MVC project that uses a MYSQL database and need to call a stored procedure from it. I've seen examples of how to access an SQL database stored procedure and attempted to copy it over and convert it to use MySql.Data.MySqlClient classes (instead of the System.Data.SqlClient classes). Can someone help me to understand why I'm getting the below error? Am I missing something... is there a different method I should use in the MyDBContext method below for MYSQL that I'm missing? (I haven't found too many people that use MYSQL stored procedures in MVC and I understand it's a rare case, but really need this for my situation. All stack overflow answerd questions I'm seeting are not using MySQL along with MVC. Thanks...)

**The Error when I try to call db.GetContinentList():** "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE dbName.ContinentListGet; expected 4, got 0"

My code...

**Controller test code  (Just looping through the results as a test to be sure it works):**

```
private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var continentList = db.GetContinentList(1, "M", 1, 0);
    var result = "";

    foreach (sp_ContinentList c in continentList)
    {
        result = result + c.Common_Name + "(" + c.Scientific_Name + ")<br />";
    }

    return Content(result);
}
```

**Model Created: (I made sure it matches the output of the stored procedure resultset columns)**

```
public class sp_ContinentList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Common_Name { get; set; }
    public string Scientific_Name { get; set; }
    public int Profile { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
}
```

**MyDBContext.cs Code:**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("MyDbContextConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyDbInitializer());
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<sp_ContinentList> GetContinentList(int continent, string group, int profile, int createCache)
    {
        MySqlParameter continentParam = new MySqlParameter("@vContinent", MySqlDbType.Int16);
        continentParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        continentParam.Value = continent;

        MySqlParameter groupParam = new MySqlParameter("@vGroup", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, group);
        groupParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        MySqlParameter profileParam = new MySqlParameter("@vProfile", MySqlDbType.Int16);
        profileParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        profileParam.Value = profile;

        MySqlParameter createCacheParam = new MySqlParameter("@vCreateCache", MySqlDbType.Int16);
        createCacheParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        createCacheParam.Value = createCache;

        MySqlParameter[] spParams = new MySqlParameter[] {
            continentParam, groupParam, profileParam, createCacheParam
        };

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<sp_ContinentList>("ContinentListGet", spParams);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer from the below stack overflow link (it's not using MVC, but from imitating MomentSurfer's way of calling the stored procedure after buildling the MySqlParameter objects, this worked for me):

Link:
[Using the entity framework with a MySQL DB and the model designer doesn't pickup stored proc parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011062/using-the-entity-framework-with-a-mysql-db-and-the-model-designer-doesnt-pickup)

```
public virtual ObjectResult<sp_ContinentList> GetContinentList(Nullable<int> continent, string group, Nullable<int> profile, Nullable<int> createCache)
{
    MySqlParameter continentParam = new MySqlParameter("vContinent", MySqlDbType.Int16);
    continentParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    continentParam.Value = continent;

    MySqlParameter groupParam = new MySqlParameter("vGroup", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    groupParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    groupParam.Value = group;

    MySqlParameter profileParam = new MySqlParameter("vProfile", MySqlDbType.Int16);
    profileParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    profileParam.Value = profile;

    MySqlParameter createCacheParam = new MySqlParameter("vCreateCache", MySqlDbType.Int16);
    createCacheParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    createCacheParam.Value = createCache;

    MySqlParameter[] spParams = new MySqlParameter[] {
    continentParam, groupParam, profileParam, createCacheParam
    };

    // New/Additional code needed:
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("CALL ContinentListGet(@vContinent, @vGroup, @vProfile, @vCreateCache)");
    string commandText = sb.ToString();

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<sp_ContinentList>(commandText, spParams);
}
```

I didn't realize that I had to actually say "CALL sproc_name()" as command text, and the way I was passing the params was also incorrect and needed further attention. I don't think this is a duplicate though because the other example isn't a MVC Database-first/DBContext example (this might be useful to someone who ever chooses to use MVC Database-first using a MySQL database).. but I'll let you guys decide.